# OpenCL in Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, opencl, tesseract, nvidia

Hi I am trying to compile the tesseract-OCR engine in Cygwin.My Host machine is running windows 7 and i have the NVIDIA toolkit installed. I am unable to find a good answer as to how to link the headers required. Tesseract is a Makefile project and when i run the ./configure script i get the following output.

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib --enable-opencl                          checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
fatal: Not a git repository: './.git'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking --enable-graphics argument... yes
checking whether to disable cube... no
checking --enable-embedded argument... no
checking for g++ option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking --enable-opencl argument... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking CL/cl.h usability... no
checking CL/cl.h presence... no
checking for CL/cl.h... no
checking OpenCL/cl.h usability... no
checking OpenCL/cl.h presence... no
checking for OpenCL/cl.h... no
checking tiffio.h usability... yes
checking tiffio.h presence... yes
checking for tiffio.h... yes
checking for clGetPlatformIDs in -lOpenCL... no
configure: error: Required OpenCL headers not found!
```

The last few lines indicate that i have missing header files. 
Online resources don't seem to have enough information regarding how to link the opencl files from my host system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the configure script if some environment variables must be set.

Comment: Was the first thing i did. Funny thing is setting LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS works when i try compiling on a linux VM. using CYGWIN i tried doing the same by adding a **/cygdrive/c/...**  prefix but it doesn't seem to be able to access the directories. I checked permisions and other kinks that may be causing this issue. But i'm having no luck.